# Format a list to show as coordinates

Tags: python

I am trying to format my list to show as coordinates. I have managed to get an output and store them in a location list. Below is the following code:

```
def Number_Generated(x_range, y_range):
    Number_Generated = random.randint(x_range, y_range)
    return Number_Generated
    
def generate_map(locations):
    Mylist = []
    for x in range (locations):
        Mylist.append(Number_Generated(-100, 100))
    return Mylist

Location_List = generate_map(100)
print(Location_List)
```

I get the following output:

```
[35, -40, 63, -57, -41, -62, 0, 35, 18, 41, -84, -99, 42, 7, 39, 74, 24, -69, 51, -95, -59, -87, 85, -86, -98, 48, -36, -34, -22, -42, 7, 99, -67, 84, 75, -2, -74, 25, -60, -33, -97, -35, 99, 53, 48, 37, 24, -73, -2, -53, -53, 58, -36, 7, 81, -40, -9, -61, -66, 50, 89, -65, -29, -3, -9, -19, -75, -14, 72, -56, 59, 86, 89, -5, -42, 26, 7, -19, 31, -72, -13, 15, 14, 3, 4, -27, -44, 12, 77, -13, 87, 41, -48, -77, -98, 3, 89, -45, 7, -65]
```

How would I format this list to show the output as `[[-23, -5], [28, 93], [-7, -49]]`.

Would I need to create a nested loop?

Comment: what is the logic of forming the coordinates? How are the coordinates formed from the list?

Comment: Generate two numbers and append them to the list? `Mylist.append([Number_Generated(-100,100), Number_Generated(-100,100)])`

Answer (score 0):

You should return a list of two `randint`s from your function `Number_Generated`:

```
def Number_Generated(x_range, y_range):
    Number_Generated1 = random.randint(x_range, y_range)
    Number_Generated2 = random.randint(x_range, y_range)
    return list(Number_Generated1, Number_Generated2)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry I misread, thought that the function was already giving two numbers as output

Comment: Now it looks good. I would just `return [num1, num2]` but that should work fine for the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` to create n unique random numbers

```
def Number_Generated(x_range, y_range):
    Number_Generated = random.sample(range(x_range, y_range), 2)
    return Number_Generated
```